# Video can not be played by NetStream on iOS

Tags: ios, apache-flex, netstream

I build a view-base mobile project in Flash Builder 4.6, which aims to play a video on remote machine. The project works well in Flash Builder. When exported, installed on iPad and iPhone 4S, the aim failed. I tried to output the relevant event and found that the project could recieve the meta data of the video but failed to play the video data.

I am stuck.

The code is like this:

```
private var netConnection:NetConnection

        private var netStream:NetStream;

        private var video:Video;

        protected function onInit():void{
            netConnection = new NetConnection();
            netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netConnectStatus);

            netConnection.connect(null);

            netStream = new NetStream(netConnection);
            netStream.client = new Object();
            netStream.client.onMetaData = function (info:Object):void{
                for(var str:String in info){
                    trace(str + " "+info[str]);
                }
            }
            netStream.bufferTime = 4;
            netStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStreamStatus);
            netStream.play("http://192.168.0.101/video/video.mp4");

            video = new Video();
            video.attachNetStream(netStream);
            video.width = stage.stageWidth;
            video.height = stage.stageHeight;
            stage.addChild(video);

        }

        public function netConnectStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void{

        }

        private function netStreamStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void {
            switch(e.info.code)
            {
                case "NetStream.Buffer.Empty":
                    break;

                case "NetStream.Buffer.Full":
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @freebird I bounced your edit on this post; please try to make a more substantative change than just capitalizing some `I`s where there's plenty more to be done to make the question more readable.

Comment: @CraigRinger Sure I will take care of that next time.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert my MP4 files to FLV to get this to work. The alternative is to use StageVideo to playback MP4.

I wasn't able to use that as my app needed to play the video at specific dimensions.